# $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta) =(x-\beta)??$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials

In this product $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta) \in K[x]$, do we  take $\beta$ only once ? **Why?**

@reuns told me that (in an answer for a question that I published yesterday). And I don't believe it, because if we only take $\beta$ only once, then $f(x)=x-\beta $, so the symbol product $\prod$ it's not necessary anymore.

Now my understanding for this $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta) \in K[x]$ is that $$f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G (\alpha)} (x-\beta)=(x-\beta)\dots(x-\beta) $$ I don't know how many times, it depends on how many element are in $G(\alpha)$.

**Notes:** $K$ is a field, $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha,$ $G(\alpha)$ is the orbit of $\alpha,$ i.e. $G(\alpha)=\{\sigma(\alpha):\sigma\in G\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the comments, I don't really understand what bothers you. But I guess you did not really understand the notation $\prod$.

To simplify, let us say that $G(\alpha)=\{\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3\}$ (just to explain we make the arbitrary assumption that it has 3 elements).

Then $f(x)=\prod_{\beta \in G(\alpha)}(x-\beta)=(x-\beta_1) \cdot (x-\beta_2) \cdot (x-\beta_3)$. So yes, we take *each* $\beta$ once into account in the product.

It is the same way of saying that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n = a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots$. And again, each element $n$ of $\mathbb{N}$ is taken once in the sum.

Comment: so all the elements of the Galois group are always different?

Comment: that would make sense when saying it takes an element only once

Comment: yes, but in a group all elements are different... I mean, a set contains distinct elements

Comment: Oh I see, $G(\alpha)$ is a set, so for example $\{1,2,1\}=\{1,2\}$?

Comment: and it happens the same on $G(\alpha),$ right?

Comment: So $f(x)$ is separable

Comment: yes! Otherwise it would be infinite, with the permutation $\sigma$ you could generate each elements an infinite number of times

Comment: alright thank you so much for your help!